# What is the difference in using SDK and cURL in IBM Watson?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/alchemylanguage/overview.shtml

When is SDK used and when cURL?
What is the difference between the 2?
In the link, tutorials for both are given

Answer (score 1):

The SDK allows you to call IBM Watson APIs faster by avoiding a lot of boilerplate code in your requests.

cURL allows you to execute the APIs directly in your terminal (without having to write code) and are comprehensible by most developers. In case your favorite language doesn't have an SDK yet, you can replicate the requests by looking at the cURL command.